# syzygy in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider $f_{1}, f_{2}, f_{3} \in \mathbb{K}[x,y,z]$. How to find polynomials $g_{1}, g_{2}, g_{3} \in \mathbb{K}[x,y,z]$ such that

$$ f_{1} g_{1} + f_{2} g_{2} +  f_{3}g_{3} = 0 ?$$

Is this possible in general case?

In the particular case:

> If  $\ \ f_{1} = y - x^{2}; \ \ f_{2} = z - xy; \ \ f_{3} = 1 - xz   $, it is possible?

Other question: What the condition in $f_{1}, f_{2}, f_{3}$ or on $\mathbb{K}[x,y,z]$ for to find $g_{1}, g_{2}, g_{3}$?

Thanks!

Comment: I think $f_1(f_3) + f_2(f_3) + f_3(-f_1 - f_2) = 0 $ right ?

Comment: [Merci !] @H.H.

Answer (score 1):

$g_1=g_2=g_3=0$.

Less stupidly, $g_1=f_2f_3$, $g_2=f_1f_3$, $g_3=-2f_1f_2$.

Comment: [thanks] @Noah Schweber